# How to work with multiple checkboxes in react and collect the checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-state-management

I'm currently working on a filter component where multiple checkboxes can be selected.

Now I want to toggle the state of the checkboxes (which is currently possible and works) and store the checked checkboxes in an array.

If a checkbox is unchecked, it should of course be removed from the array. I've tried the useState hook, but without success --> The checkboxes are added multiple times and the unchecked ones are not removed..

**Here is the current status:**

```
  // Here I'm creating an array with a fixed size (based on the received data)
  const [checkboxState, setCheckboxState] = useState(new Array(receivedData.length).fill(false));
  // With this useState I wan't to collect the checked checkboxes
  const [checkedCheckboxes, setCheckedCheckboxes] = useState([]);
    
  // This is my handler method that gets triggered when a checkbox get's checked/unchecked
  // ..and toggles the state of the checkbox
  const handleCheckboxState = (position: number) => {
    const updatedCheckedState = checkboxState.map((item, index) => (index === position ? !item : item));
    setCheckboxState(updatedCheckedState);
    collectCheckedCheckboxes();
  };

  // With this method I wan't to push the checked checkboxes into the array
  // ..and remove the unchecked ones
  const collectCheckedCheckboxes = () => {
    checkboxState.map((item, index) => {
      if (item === true) {
        return checkedCheckboxes.push(receivedData[index]);
      } else {
        return checkedCheckboxes.slice(index, 1);
      }
    });
  };
```

**The checkboxes are rendered like this:**

```
  <div className="checkboxes">
    {receivedData?.map((data, index) => (
      <CheckBox
        value={data.value}
        checked={checkboxState[index]}
        onChange={() => handleCheckboxState(index)}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CheckBox`-component does not contain a `key` property. This is helpful for React to identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

I also do not understand why you have two states, `checkboxState` and `checkedCheckboxes`. Is there another reason for this? I think this would be easier with a single state which holds the indexes (or values) of the checked checkboxes.

[update after comments]

The code below is the desired solution by OP to have the selected object values in a React state.

```
const { useState } = React;

const Checkboxes = () => {
  // With this useState I wan't to collect the checked checkboxes
  const [checkedCheckboxes, setCheckedCheckboxes] = useState([]);

  // This is my handler method that gets triggered when a checkbox get's checked/unchecked
  // ..and toggles the state of the checkbox
  const handleCheckboxChange = (data) => {
    const isChecked = checkedCheckboxes.some(checkedCheckbox => checkedCheckbox.value === data.value)
    if (isChecked) {
      setCheckedCheckboxes(
        checkedCheckboxes.filter(
          (checkedCheckbox) => checkedCheckbox.value !== data.value
        )
      );
    } else {
      setCheckedCheckboxes(checkedCheckboxes.concat(data));
    }
  };

  const receivedData = [{ value: "A" }, { value: "B" }, { value: "C" }];

  return (
    <>
      <div className="checkboxes">
        <h1>Checkboxes:</h1>
        {receivedData?.map((data, index) => (
          <input
            key={`cb-${index}`}
            value={data.value}
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checkedCheckboxes.some(checkedCheckbox => checkedCheckbox.value === data.value)}
            onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(data)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>State:</h1>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(checkedCheckboxes, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Checkboxes />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: I just posted a simple version of my code. I also inserted the key :)

Thanks for your approach, but how do you track the state of the checkboxes?

..and concat removes elements from an array?

Comment: `.concat` adds the element to an array, and `.filter` removes the element.
You only need to track the checked checkboxes. The available checkboxes are known due to `receivedData`, so an array of the checked checkboxes should be sufficient?

Comment: Oh right, my mistake. I'll give it a try and give you feedback. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry pressed enter a bit too fast after the first line, I have just updated my previous comment. Good luck :)

Comment: Unfortunately does not work. The first click goes blank, so that only from the second click something is added to the array. In addition, the object that I need is not added to the array, but something strange (I think only the index of the selected checkbox). Even when removing, one checkbox always remains in the array at the end, although all are unchecked.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work in the example below in codepen, maybe something is up with the `CheckBox`-component? Sorry cannot paste the code here due to 500 characters limit.

https://codepen.io/allardvanderouw/pen/PojOjrO

Comment: Yes, but it doesn‘t add the objects to the checked checkboxes array, only the indexes. Every checked checkbox should be an object in the array. This array of objects I need to pass to another compnent later.

Comment: Aha, you want the selected objects. I have updated the codepen for that; https://codepen.io/allardvanderouw/pen/PojOjrO

Comment: Now it works! Thanks a lot :) - If you want, you can update your answer above, so that I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: That's nice to hear :) You're welcome. I have updated the solution with the code from codepen. Good luck with your project!